# Cómo implementar la autenticación con Google sin usar métodos obsoletos?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Cuando implemento la autenticación con Google, me dice que los métodos `startActivityForResult()` y `onActivityResult()` están deprecated.

> startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int): Unit' is deprecated.

Este es mi código

```
    binding.googleButton.setOnClickListener {
    val googleConf = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build()
    val googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConf)
    googleClient.signOut()
    startActivityForResult(googleClient.signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
   }
```

También me muestra la misma advertencia en el `onActivityResult()`

```
     override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente la documentación de firebase está desactualizada. Los métodos `startActivityForResult()` y `onActivityResult()` fueron reemplazados por la nueva API [Activity Result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Así quedaría tu código usando la nueva API:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var googleClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private val googleSignIn = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
        ...
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val googleConf = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConf)
        binding.googleButton.setOnClickListener {
            googleClient.signOut()
            googleSignIn.launch(googleClient.signInIntent)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Además debes saber que ese método para iniciar sesión con google tampoco es el más nuevo. La nueva API se llama [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started).